# Activate dropout during prediction using Tensorflow keras.Sequential()

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

I use Tensorflow 2.0 with Keras and the `Sequential()` API to create a simple model:

```
def create_model():
    model = keras.Sequential([
        keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(8,8)),
        keras.layers.Dense(32, activation="relu"),
        keras.layers.Dropout(DROPOUT_RATE),
        keras.layers.Dense(16, activation="relu"),
        keras.layers.Dropout(DROPOUT_RATE),
        keras.layers.Dense(2, activation="softmax")
    ])

    model.compile(optimizer="adam",
                  loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
                  metrics=["accuracy"])
    return model

my_model = create_model()
```

How can I activate the dropout rate during prediction? And would it be possible to use different dropout rates during prediction?

Answer (score 1):

In TF 2, you are probably using eager mode, right?

You can simply:

```
outputs = my_model(numpy_inputs, training=True)
#maybe you need also:
outputs = outputs.numpy()
```

As for changing the rates, you need to follow @sxeros link.

Comment: Is it really that simple? I found much more complicated hacks to enable dropout during prediction. How can I change the dropout rate during prediction? I tried to follow @sxeros' link, but did not understand the approach.

Comment: On eager mode, yes, it's that simple. But changing the rate is more complicated. You can't avoid creating custom layers for that, because Keras layers take an "integer" as rate, while you should have a "tensor" for rate. I may try to code it later. I'm late.